# How to know if a network interface is tap, tun, bridge or physical?

Tags: networking, kernel, ip, bridge, tap

As far as I know, there are 4 main types of network interfaces in Linux: tun, tap, bridge and physical.

When I'm doing sys admin on machines running KVM, I usually come across tap, bridge and physical interfaces on the same machine, without being able to tell them apart. I can't see any significant differences in `ifconfig` results, as in `ip` results.

How can I know if an interface is a tun, tap, bridge, or physical?

*note: I don't claim that there are no other types of network interfaces in Linux, but I know only these 4.*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to distinguish them. Poking around in `/sys/class/net` I found the following distinctions:

- Physical devices have a `/sys/class/net/eth0/device` symlink
- Bridges have a `/sys/class/net/br0/bridge` directory
- TUN and TAP devices have a `/sys/class/net/tap0/tun_flags` file
- Bridges and loopback interfaces have `00:00:00:00:00:00` in `/sys/class/net/lo/address`

Comment: Good idea to look in /sys/

Comment: Virtual devices may also have such a `device` symlink: `ls -l /sys/class/net/lan1/device` Shows `/sys/class/net/lan1/device -> ../../../dsa.0` on a router running OpenWrt (embedded Linux). I found that physical Interfaces have an Interrupt entry in the output of `ifconfig`. It is strange that such a simple question about an Interface seems so hard to answer. Investigation continues ...

Comment: How about a ppp virtual device?

Answer (score 31):

Regarding TUN and TAP devices: it is not enough to make the check above.

The reason is that there may be cases when we create a TUN device and (by error)
call it tap10; or create a TAP device and name it tun10.  So, how can I know if it is a tun device or a tap device, since both of course will have "tun_flags" entries?

The answer is to run `ethtool -i tunOrTapDeviceName`.

- In case of a TAP device we will get: "bus-info: tap".
- In case of a TUN device we will get: "bus-info: tun".

#### Example

```
$ ethtool -i tapfffb93e9-6a
driver: tun
version: 1.6
firmware-version:
bus-info: tap
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Comment: Isn't there a ethtool command to find if an interface it physical or bridge?

Comment: This answer is the more concise and general-purpose solution.

Comment: @madcode In the general case you want the `driver` field.  bridges will show `driver: bridge`.  Unfortunately tun/tap both show up as `driver: tun`, breaking the pattern :).

Comment: Yes this is the answer. The other one only tells you if the intf is virtual of not! You can name a tap interface with a name that gives no indication of the nature of the interface

Answer (score 17):

You can use the more-or-less undocumented `-d` option to `ip(8)`, which tells you the type of certain devices including tun, tap & veth:

e.g.

```
$ ip -d a
[regular devices]
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:c8:12:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 
tun
```

...note `tun` on the last line.

You can also use `-d` with `ip l`.

Comment: iproute2 is such a nice tool. Too bad so many features are hard to discover.

Comment: What version of iproute2 supports this "-d" feature?

Comment: "-d" was added in commit 1d9348398 in 2007, just before v2.6.23-071016 was tagged. It was sort-of documented (in the man page) in commit a5eafa9a5 which made it into tag v3.18.0 in late 2014.

Comment: just for clarity on this, -d is -details

Answer (score 8):

This command will do the job:

**ip tuntap**

Result example:

```
vnet0: tap
```

or with details:

**ip -details tuntap**

Result example:

```
vnet0: tap
    Attached to processes: qemu-system-x86(2225)
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by @ben `ip -d l` gives details about the interfaces among which the interface type. However the information is a bit messy and *if you know what type of interfaces you are interrested in* another possibility is to use `ip link show type TYPE` which will list all interfaces of that type.

where

```
TYPE := { vlan | veth | vcan | vxcan | dummy | ifb | macvlan | macvtap |
          bridge | bond | team | ipoib | ip6tnl | ipip | sit | vxlan |
          gre | gretap | erspan | ip6gre | ip6gretap | ip6erspan |
          vti | nlmon | team_slave | bond_slave | bridge_slave |
          ipvlan | ipvtap | geneve | vrf | macsec | netdevsim | rmnet }
```

Answer (score 0):

`nmcli device show`
will show in GENERAL.TYPE

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         as0t0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     as0t0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.27.224.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.27.224.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::36f0:2ea:69db:490/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         as0t1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     as0t1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.27.225.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.27.225.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::abfe:7b9c:4ab2:ea70/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it depends greatly on what operating system you're referring to.

For example, on FreeBSD the default devices for:

- tun(4) devices are tun[0-9]+ (and likely have the "groups: tun" attribute unless removed with `ifconfig tunX -group tun`)
- tap(4) devices are tap[0-9]+ (and likely have the "groups: tap" attribute unless removed with `ifconfig tapX -group tap`)
- bridge(4) devices are bridge[0-9]+ (and likely have the "groups: bridge" attribute unless removed with `ifconfig bridgeX -group bridge`))
- physical devices aren't

If the incidental mention of Linux is crucial to the question, adding it as a tag may help to define the scope of your query.  The specific distribution of interest may be helpful as well.