# How can I find out the ownership of a tap interface?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, tap

I can set up a persistent Linux tap interface and make it owned by a specific user and group with one of these:

```
tunctl -u someuser -g somegroup -t example.tap
ip tuntap add dev example.tap mode tap user someuser group somegroup
```

I can confirm the interface is there and see a bit of information about it with

```
ip link list dev example.tap
```

But how, after the fact, can I find out which user or group the interface is owned by?  `ip tuntap` seems very sparsely documented and `ip link list` doesn't seem to show ownership.

Answer (score 6):

An answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40560/how-to-know-if-a-network-interface-is-tap-tun-bridge-or-physical) suggested looking in /sys/, which turns out to help.  For example:

```
cat /sys/class/net/example.tap/owner
```

reveals the uid of the owning user, or -1 if the interface isn't owned by a user.  Similarly with `group` substituted for `owner` to get group ownership.  I'm not sure if there's a "cleaner" method that doesn't involve delving into kernel filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

Run `ip(8)` with the (under-documented) `-d` option:

```
$ sudo ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap user ben
$ ip -d link show tap0
40: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c9:63:71:fa:8f:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 
    tun type tap pi off vnet_hdr off persist on user ben addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

Note `user ben` on the last line.